# A disk read error occurred Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart new hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, sata

I searched a lot of sites, and I still can't find the solution. 
I just bought new hard drive (sata 2) and I replaced the old one (sata 3). When it started to boot installation started from USB (windows 7 - it asked me for partitions...). Then computer restarted and bios showed me this message "a disk read error occurred Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart". What can I do?

Comment: Could you please clarify if the installation of Windows was complete before you got the message? This could be either an issue with the PC detecting the HDD or a problem with the bootsector. Did you had any other HDDs connected to your PC while it was installing the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could cause by a **bad sector** or **faulty HDD** or **bad connected** or **dusty HDD power cable**.
also check if SATA port is well connected.

if non of above solved the problem, try changing used SATA socket on your Mainboard or use another power cable.